# Chrome DevTools: Remote DOM modifications

Tags: c#, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating a small application that should remotelly control the
browser window: navigate, fill forms, etc. I'm trying to archive the
goal using Chrome Remote Debugging and C#. Currently the prototype
connnects to browser, get the list of available pages and establish
WebSocket connection.

1. Start chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9123
2. Connecto to ws://localhost:9123/devtools/page/1 and send:

   ```
   request: { "id": 1, "method": "DOM.setOuterHTML", "params": {"nodeId": 1, "outerHTML": ""}}
   ```

It looks wrong but no error is returned.

Code:

```
       var client = new WebClient();
       var pages = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:9123/json");
       Console.WriteLine(pages); // works well, displays JSON with info about pages

       // create WebSocket
       var socket = new WebSockets.WebSocket("ws://localhost:9123/devtools/page/1");
       // it should print messages to console:
       socket.OnMessage += (sender, eventdata) => Console.WriteLine(eventdata);

       // works well - sends and recieves handshaking messages
       socket.Connect();

       Console.WriteLine("\nType \"exit\" to exit.\n");

       string data;
       while (true)
       {
           Thread.Sleep(500);
           Console.Write("> ");
           data = Console.ReadLine();
           if (data == "exit")
               break;
           // sends data:
           socket.Send(data);
       }
```

How data is sending into the WebSocket stream:

```
           byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
           _wsStream.WriteByte(0x00);
           _wsStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
           _wsStream.WriteByte(0xff);
```

And the reading never returns:

```
   private void Message() // started in different thread
   {
       while (_readyState == WsState.Open)
       {
           string data = Receive(); // does _wsStream.ReadByte(); and stops on it forever
           var handler = OnMessage;
           if (null != handler && data != null)
               handler(this, data);
       }
   }
```

Could you please help me with the command syntax and troubleshootings
the issue...

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use `WebSocket4Net` NuGet package.

```
using WebSocket4Net;

//Create new socket connection
WebSocket socket = new WebSocket(tab.webSocketDebuggerUrl);
socket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
socket.Open();
socket.Send("String to send");

private static void Ss_MessageReceived(object sender, WebSocket4Net.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Handle here response from server
}
```